# ifconfig and systemd-networkd are not synced and behaving differently

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, ifconfig, systemd-networkd

I have two questions if someone can help: I have a linux based system.

1. I configured the /etc/systemd/network/00-eth0.network file with IP, Gateway, and MAC addresses. After I restart the systemd-networkd damen and run ifconfig on eth0, I only see the MAC address there and no IP or Gateway are showing.
   If I use ip command to configure IP and Gateway, it shows under ifconfig, but not under the /etc/systemd/network/00-eth0.network file.

Can someone explain why two utilities are not synced?

2. If I configure the NIC using ip command, I can ping the IP i set for the NIC. However, if I configure the NIC using systemd-networkd, I cannot ping the IP of the NIC and it shows the following message. ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
   Why is that the case?

Setting IP/Gateway using ip and systemd-networkd should result in the same behaviors, however I am seeing that these two utilities are not synced

Comment: `Can someone explain why two utilities are not synced?` because that's not how linux works. setting up using systemd-networkd would likely use same procedure as `ip` to perform the configuration using the config in that file ... `I configured the /etc/systemd/network/00-eth0.network` perhaps you did it wrong

Comment: What _actual_ configuration did you put in the eth0.network file, and what exact options did you use with the 'ip' command?